# Send JSON from PHP to JAVA api

Tags: java, php, jquery, json, api

I've been looking for the answer on this page, but I speak little English, so I may have not found the correct answer.

Well, I'm programming a cart with jquery to send it to a server in php. On the other hand I have a java api that receives json.

My question: how can i send a json from php to java api, as I have to insert a bd (inserted in java)?

Pd: it is a class project.

Thanks for the answers, I've been looking for the answer 2 days.

Comment: This is entirely dependant on how the Java API works. JSON is just a string of text and you could submit this to an API using Curl if it is remote or via the shell_exec or sockets if it is running locally

Comment: the API has a route called transaction that receives a json using post the thing is that i dont know how to send from php

Comment: I would suggest experimenting sending JSON to the API manually first before you write a line of PHP. Check out Advanced Rest Client for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Comment: i have used the rest client in mozilla, and it works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a curl you can call the action JAVA API with the JSON cart.
For example:

```
$urladdress = "www.javaapicart.com/getCart.jsp"
$data = "json=".json_encode($dataCart)

$ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urladdress); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 

curl_exec ($ch) or die(curl_error($ch)); 
curl_close ($ch);
```

And in the JAVA API decode the JSON string and insert in the database

Comment: $ch = curl_init();//cant initiate

Comment: You need activate the module php_curl.dll

Comment: If you have xampp, go in c://yourxampppath/php/ and edit the php.ini, and in the line ;extension=php_curl.dll, delete the ";" and restart

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the json your php is sending, your java API should be able to parse it with, say http://json.org

The java API in that page will allow you to build `JSONObjects` based on the JSON string returned by php, and you can use them as a kind of Maps (`String` keys leading to properties on the object)